# Get Windows display settings

Tags: vba, winapi, windows-xp

I'm trying to find out how to retrieve the user's display settings through the windows API. Specifically, the settings found under `Display Settings -> Appearance -> Font Size` and `Display Settings -> Appearance -> Advanced`, particularly the font size/face/colour settings.

I've dug around in the Windows API documentation (which I'm not altogether familiar with) and looked through `GetTextMetrics`, `GetSystemMetrics` and `SystemParametersInfo` but couldn't spot anything in those. Where can these settings be found?

I only need to be able to *read* these values, not alter them, if that makes any difference on the functions I need to be using. I'm trying to surface these in VBA.

Comment: Yes, those, and GetSysColor().  Do be specific about what *particular* setting you want to read back.